# Butter crunch French bread topping

Tags: baking, bread

Does anyone know what's in the topping that gets baked onto butter crunch French bread? I think that it is cheese but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you provide an image and description? Is it something from a specific store/bakery? I'm not familiar with this, and Google (web search or image search) shows all kinds of different things, so I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: I know you didn't say this, but you aren't by any chance thinking of "Dutch Crunch bread", are you?

Comment: yes I think that's what it might be called. my local bakery calls it butter crunch but i'm pretty sure it's the Dutch one

Comment: If it is Dutch crunch (which is particularly popular in the SF Bay Area) then it's also known as tiger bread in the UK. Either name will get you tons of recipes (and images), which should be enough to confirm whether it's what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your bread look like this (photo)? From your comments, it seems that you think your bakery's "butter crunch French bread" may be the same bread which is called "Dutch crunch," among other names. Since no one else is answering this question, I'll take a stab at it even though I have never baked any of this bread, & tasted it for the first time just now.

In my supermarket, they call it "Dutch *crust*[image: see photo]," and the topping's ingredients are called out separately: Rice Flour, Palm Shortening, Sugar, Active Dry Yeast.

Semifreddi's Bakery website   http://www.semifreddis.com/products   lists all the bread's ingredients:  Enriched Flour (wheat flour, malted barley flour, niacin, reduced iron, thiamine mononitrate, riboflavin, folic acid), Water, Safflower and/or Sunflower and/or Expeller Pressed Canola Oil, Sugar, Rice Flour, Sea Salt, and Yeast.

Wikipedia describes Dutch crunch bread as having *sesame oil* and rice flour in the topping, although neither of my examples mention the sesame oil, just the rice flour... But no cheese in any I see. Any cheesy topping is probably not the same as what I am thinking of.

Comment: it doesn't taste cheesy it just looks like baked cheese to me... I'll give this a stab and see the results. thanks